# Discontinuity and riemann integrability

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left\{x\right\}$ be the fractional part of number $x$. Consider the function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\{nx\}}{n^2}$$ How can I find all discontinuities of $f$, and show that they form a countable dense set. Can you help me to show that the function is Riemann integrable over a bounded interval?

Comment: the fractional part function is periodic with period one so $ {ax} $ is periodic $ 1/a$ for each 'a'. discontinuities are $ 1/n $ for n=1,2,3,4,5....

Comment: The series converges normally, so it is bounded, and continuous at every $x$ such that all functions $\{nx\}$ are continuous at $x$. Where are these functions discontinuous?

Comment: For the second part, use the fact that if $f$ is the uniform limit of a series each of whose terms is integrable over $[a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$.

Comment: Another way is to use Lebesgue  theorem stating that a bounded function $f$ on a segment is a Riemann integrable iff the set of the discontinuity points of $f$  has the Lebesgue measure zero.